# sqlldr style error logging in Oracle external tables

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm currently trying to get the error messages we get from our Oracle external table loading process to match the level of detail we get when loading via sqlldr.

Currently if I load a file in sqlldr and a record fails I get this error message which is pretty useful - I get the record number, the actual column name that failed and the record in a bad file.

```
Record 4: Rejected - Error on table ERROR_TEST, column COL1.
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I've got an external table along with an INSERT statement to a target table that logs errors to a DBMS_ERRLOG table but this is the equivalent error message from that process.

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Whilst this process has the benefit of recording the actual record in a table so you can see column name mappings it doesn't actually list which column has the issue. This is a big issue when looking at tables with many columns...

It looks as though I can have the REJECT LIMIT on the external table itself which will give the same above error but that will then lose the ERR table logging. I'm guessing it's a case of one or the other?

Comment: With the real data types and `reject limit 0` in your external table definition, the insert into the other table will fail (because the select will) and essentially tell you that you need to look at the external log, which has the details you want. With a higher reject limit you might not get any indication that there were any issues, so don't know to look. But that's true of an error logging table too. Is there a reason to not just use the external table log? And no, you can't have both,sadly.

Comment: Annoyingly some of the files we load have different 'types' of records in, meaning records 5 - 10 might have 15 fields populated and the next 20 might have only 5 fields populated with different data types. This means our external tables are generic VARCHAR2 datatypes and we catch any errors at the INSERT level.

Comment: I see. I guess you *could* have multiple external tables (one per real target table) with real data types, and have each one use a different preprocessor clause so only the relevant rows are included... but that might be overcomplicating things a bit.

Comment: Last time I looked you were unable to use the pre-processor clause if you have Oracle VPD enabled, a real pain :(